# Rust - how to efficiently remove characters from beggining of string?

Tags: string, performance, memory, rust

I have a long string stored in a variable in Rust. I often remove some characters from its front with a `drain` method and use the value returned from it:

```rust
my_str.drain(0..i).collect::<String>();
```

The problem is, that draining from this string is done *really often* in the program and it's slowing it down a lot (it takes ~99.6% of runtime). This is a very expensive operation, since every time, the entire string has to be moved left in the memory.

I do not drain from the end of the string at all (which should be much faster), just from the front.

How can I make this more efficient? Is there some alternative to `String`, that uses a different memory layout, which would be better for this use case?

Comment: And can you just reverse it and then reverse again before using? Prefixes become suffixes at that point, and if you rarely need to access actual value - it should work. Also, you can use an iterator and move to the next char instead of removing the prefix. Also you can just store index position, pointing to current beginning of the string, and trim everything finally. Probably more context (code sample, plus explanation whether you access the string between removals and how long string and prefixes are) could rescue this question from "needs debugging details" closing.

Comment: `VecDeque<char>` with `pop_front` method may be useful too.

Comment: `VecDeque` looks good @SUTerliakov

Comment: Or keep the full `String` somewhere and use `&str` and subslices: `my_str[i..]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use slices because of the lifetimes, you could use a type that provides shared-ownership like `SharedString` from the [shared-string](https://crates.io/crates/shared-string) crate or `Str` from the [bytes-utils](https://crates.io/crates/bytes-utils) crate. The former looks more fully-featured but both provide methods that can take the prefix from a string in O(1) because the original data is never moved.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Jmb, keeping the original string intact and working with slices is certainly a big win.

I don't know, from the question, the context and usage of these strings, but this quick and dirty benchmark shows a substantial difference in performances.

This benchmark is flawed because there is a useless `clone()` at each repetition, there is no warm-up, there is no black-box for the result, there are no statistics... but it just gives an idea.

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn with_drain(mut my_str: String) -> usize {
    let mut total = 0;
    'work: loop {
        for &i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().cycle() {
            if my_str.len() < i {
                break 'work;
            }
            let s = my_str.drain(0..i).collect::<String>();
            total += s.len();
        }
    }
    total
}

fn with_slice(my_str: String) -> usize {
    let mut total = 0;
    let mut pos = 0;
    'work: loop {
        for &i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().cycle() {
            let next_pos = pos + i;
            if my_str.len() <= next_pos {
                break 'work;
            }
            let s = &my_str[pos..next_pos];
            pos = next_pos;
            total += s.len();
        }
    }
    total
}

fn main() {
    let my_str="I have a long string stored in a variable in Rust.
I often remove some characters from its front with a drain method and use the value returned from it:
my_str.drain(0..i).collect::<String>();
The problem is, that draining from this string is done really often in the program and it's slowing it down a lot (it takes ~99.6% of runtime). This is a very expensive operation, since every time, the entire string has to be moved left in the memory.
I do not drain from the end of the string at all (which should be much faster), just from the front.
How can I make this more efficient? Is there some alternative to String, that uses a different memory layout, which would be better for this use case?
".to_owned();
    let repeat = 1_000_000;
    let instant = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..repeat {
        let _ = with_drain(my_str.clone());
    }
    let drain_duration = instant.elapsed();
    let instant = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..repeat {
        let _ = with_slice(my_str.clone());
    }
    let slice_duration = instant.elapsed();
    println!("{:?} {:?}", drain_duration, slice_duration);
}
/*
$ cargo run --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/release/prog`
5.017018957s 310.466253ms
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @SUTerliakov, using `VecDeque<char>` in this case is much more effective than `String` either with the `pop_front` method or the `drain` method (when draining from the front of course)

Comment: `VecDeque<char>` has the downside of storing the string essentially in UTF-32, which is less compact than `String`'s UTF-8, and is incompatible with `str`.